# Detect cause of program exit

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I have a console application written in C# targeting .NET Core for Linux. I'm facing a bug where rarely the application would just exit for seemingly no reason. I'm also unsure if this is an issue with the runtime itself or a library that I'm referencing.

I tried adding these extra event handlers:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionTrapper;
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += CurrentDomainOnProcessExit;
AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading += DefaultOnUnloading;
```

And I see no unhandled exception. The second two functions are also called properly and display log messages so I don't think the kernel is terminating the program.

How could I proceed to debug this issue?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping all in a try-catch block?

Comment: The program is multi-threaded and asynchronous. So a global try-catch isn't possible. That's why I use the UnhandledExceptionTrapper.